# Address of operator and r-value

Tags: c, pointers

There is code part below and I have a question about that.

Although I expect the compiler error, the ouput of this program is 2 5. From my point of view, &a+1 statement should lead to compiler error. The reason is that (a + 1) firstly is executed due to operator precedence and (a+1) statement points 2 in the array. Then, the address of operator (&) has (a + 1) operand but (a + 1) is an r-value expression and therefore &a+1 should cause a compiler error.

What is my fault?

```
int main()
{

    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);

    printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(ptr-1));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence - don't mix up unary `+` and the addition operator `+`. Or the `&` address-of unary and the `&` bitwise and.

Comment: For an array, `&a` is `a` or `&a[0]`. `&a+1` is `a+1`. So, no issues. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70192415/does-the-address-of-a-pointer-change-when-using-malloc/70192569#70192569

Comment: @CraigEstey `&a` is *not* a. The type of `&a` is "pointer to an array of 5 ints", so `&a+1` points to just past the end of `a`. That is why, when cast to an `int*`, the (ptr-1) expression yields the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays decay to pointer. Any of those pointers reference the same address in memory. The difference is in the type of this pointer.

```
int arr[5];
```

1. `arr` and `&arr[0]` have type **pointer to int** (`int *`)
2. `&arr` has type of **pointer to five elements integer array** ( `int (*)[5]`)

> Then, the address of operator (&) has (a + 1) operand but (a + 1) is
> an r-value expression and therefore &a+1 should cause a compiler
> error.

No, the `&` operator is applied to `a` not to `a + 1`. `&a + 1` === `(&a) + 1`

In your case `&a` is a pointer to 5 int elements. `&a + 1` references the **next array of 5 int elements**, not the next element of the array `a`. Then you assign this value to `int *` pointer and derefence the previous `int` value. As pointer `ptr` is referencing the element one **past** the last element of the the array `a` so the previous element is the **last** element of the array `a`

Comment: The conversion of `&a+1` to `int *` is not fully defined by the C standard. (It is partially defined in C 2018 6.3.2.3 7.)  In particular, `(int *) (&a+1)` is not defined to be yield a value equivalent to `a + 5`. So “As pointer `ptr` is referencing the element one past the last element of the the array `a` so the previous element is the **last** element of the array `a`” is not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil IMO your interpretation goes too far. `It is one past minus one` which is 100% fine.  Otherwise, any reference would not be guaranteed line in this example.  https://godbolt.org/z/rfzjaYP6a

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the actual operator precedence.

The unary address-of operator `&` has *higher* precedence than the binary addition operator `+`.  So the in the expression `&a+1` the address-of operator is first applied to `a` which is valid because `a` is an lvalue, then 1 is added to the result.

The actual precedence rules come from the grammar in the C standard, although it can be tricky for a novice to deduce what they actually are.
A good reference for operator precedence can be found here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

From this chart, you can see that the binary bitwise AND operator `&` does indeed have lower precedence than the binary addition operator `+`, but the unary address-of operator `&` has higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Here you define the object `a` to be an array of 5 integers.

```
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Here, you use `&a`, which mean, a pointer to an object which is an array of 5 integers -- `sizeof(a)=5*sizeof(int)`.

The object `&a+1` is a pointer to an array of 5 integers as well (if you do `(&a+1)-a` you will get `sizeof(a)`), which is `5*sizeof(int)`. So, `ptr` will point 5 integers beyond `a` (which is the same as`a[0]`).

```
    int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
```

Next, you access `*(ptr-1)`, but this time the pointer arithmetics will subtract only `sizeof(int)` from `ptr`, as ptr has type `pointer to int` -- you will access an integer at an address `ptr[-1]`, which falls inside the first array of five elements, `(&a)[0]`, it points on its last integer.

```
    printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(ptr-1));
```

`*(a+1)` is simple, it is just `a[1]`, of type integer.

```
     &(a[1])       ptr-1 ptr
     |              |    |
     V              V    V
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
^                        ^                        ^
+------------------------+------------------------+
|                        |                        |
&a                       &a+1                     &a+2
```